# Javascript copy to clipboard only gets the first record

Tags: javascript

I have a button that is generated for each record from a search.
The buttons function is to copy the file number of that record to the clipboard, however no matter which button is clicked it only copies the first records file number?

```
<imgage alt="Copy File No. <%=ShowFileNo%><delim> to clipboard" name="<%=ShowFileNo%>" src="Style/Copy2.png" onclick="copy('CopyImage');" id="CopyImage" />
```

---

```
function copy(controlId) {
  var control = document.getElementById(controlId);
  if (control) {
    var controlValue = control.name + '<delim>';
    window.clipboardData.setData('Text', controlValue);
    alert("'" + controlValue + "'" + ' copied to clipboard')
    window.close();
  }
}
```

Thanks
Darren

Comment: Do these different records have distinct `id`s or is the `id` always `'CopyImage'`?  Maybe instead of passing an `id`, pass `this` and rename the `controlId` to control.

Comment: Are you sure that you pass different `controlId`s to the function?

Comment: You do realize this only works in IE?

Comment: Aware of it only working in IE - all good because only developing for IE :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs must be unique.  This intrinsic to both HTML and XML.

You can change your onclick to this: `onclick="copy(this);"`

And change your reference as such:

```
function copy(control) {
// var control = document.getElementById(controlId);
  if (control) {
    var controlValue = control.name + '<delim>';
    window.clipboardData.setData('Text', controlValue);
    alert("'" + controlValue + "'" + ' copied to clipboard')
    window.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I thought as much just wasnt sure of the best way to handle it.